# NVIDIA drivers fail to run on Dell E6510

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

After changing the video drivers setting in Software & Updates | Additional Drivers...from X.Org X Server to NVIDIA driver metapackage my laptop goes to a black screen and remains there after initial cold boot and successfully entering the login credentials. I tried to revert back by selecting "Advanced options for Ubuntu" at the GRUB menu, then Linux 4.15.0-39-generic (recovery mode), Run in failsafe graphic mode, which eventually advises that I'm running in low graphics mode and the device settings could not be detected. Next is a panel to manually configure graphical mode, however whatever selection I choose the  button seems to only refresh the screen and the selection is not invoked. Any other change choices in these panels such as "edit conf file" end in the same result.

This was a perfectly fine and running 18.04.1 fully patched as of yesterday. I need to revert the video driver selection back to its previous state it would seem. Any help to do that is appreciated.

Comment: I am able to drop into command line mode from the recovery panels, however, and login as usual. Don't know how to change the graphic drivers back form there.

Comment: sudo apt-get purge nvidia*

Comment: sudo reboot      --- presto, chango, magic.....

Answer (score 0):

Get to a command prompt from the recovery path in GRUB, etc. and enter the following:

sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo reboot